# Paste excel data in python wx.ListCtrl

Tags: python, excel, wxpython

I have a problem with paste column from exel file into  wx.ListCtrl widget.

```
class base_Frame(wx.Frame):
def __init__(self,parent,title,size=(400,550),input_Label_Text='test',
             output_Label_Text='test'):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent=parent,size=size)
    self.statusbar = self.CreateStatusBar()
    self.statusbar.SetStatusText('Введите данные для расчета.')

    self.input_Label=wx.StaticText(self,label=input_Label_Text,pos=(10,5))
    self.output_Label = wx.StaticText(self, label=output_Label_Text,pos=(250,5))

    self.input_Field=wx.TextCtrl(self,pos=(5,30),size=(100,400))
    self.output_Field = wx.TextCtrl(self, pos=(110, 30), size=(270, 400))
```

When I copy/paste column fron excel sheet into wx.ListCtrl by right-click menu or ctrl-c/ctrl-v, only first value appears in widget:[values for copy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzHQP.png)

[pasted value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xgkmr.png)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved by parameter style=wx.TE_MULTILINE

```
self.input_Field=wx.TextCtrl(self,pos=(5,30),size=(100,400),style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
```